# How to type 辶 using 拼音

Tags: radicals

How does one type the radical 辶 using the standard method of entering 拼音 (as opposed to, for example, 五笔)?  (Typing "chuo" does not seem to bring this choice up on Windows using Microsoft Pinyin, though it does when I try this on Google Translate.)

In general, is there an easy way to type radicals which themselves do not exist as individual characters?

Comment: The chances are that you won't be typing it very frequently. When you need it, just copy and paste it from somewhere. I do the same with french. When I want to type an accent, I search up the word without the accent on google, and copy and paste the ascent.

Comment: Actually I plan to be typing it quite a bit as I am having Memrise quiz me on these.

Comment: 'Zou' in Mandarin, 'Chou' is just spoken by non-native/Chinese speakers.

Answer (score 5):

you need to identify the prototype of radicals.for your example，the prototype of辶is走，the ptototype of 扌is手，草for艹，水for氵，冰for冫......，then you just type the prototype and find the radical.

Comment: Interesting.  I thought the "prototype" of 辶 was 辵, not 走.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft's Chinese IME is probably not your best choice.

搜狗's IME displays `辶` by typing `chuo`.

The same is true of iOS's and OS's IMEs.

Radicials seem to have pinyin names as well, these pinyin in general should be able to type up the radicals: for example `讠` can also be typed up by inserting the pinyin `yan` into any IME (Microsoft not included, probably).

[image: 万能五笔]
[image: 万能五笔-拼音]

Comment: FWIW, "yan" brings up 讠 using Microsoft Pinyin.  So far the only one I've had trouble with is 辶.

Comment: Do you recommend 搜狗 for other reasons besides this?  How does it compare to Google's IME (which also does not seem to have this “辶" problem)?

Comment: @JonathanGleason I've never used/seen a Chinese persons computer that didn't have *搜狗* on it, that doesn't make it good, but that's saying something. It is a pretty intuitive piece of software, especially when it comes to guessing typos, a lot of Chinese people find it hard to differentiate between retroflex sounds and non-retroflex sounds (zh vs. z, ch. vs. c, sh vs. s) - and words with-or-without g on the end. Sougou will automatically 'guess' the correct word that you want.

Comment: 'Zou' in Mandarin. It sounds like 'Chou'.

Comment: @JonarhanGleason 搜狗 is just easier to use for casual speaker. For example, there are characters even many of us Chinese have trouble to write or often pronounce wrong, e.g some people read 汤匙(chi2) (soup spoon) as tang1 shi2 becasue 匙 is pronounced as shi in 钥匙(shi) (key). 搜狗 would accept the incorrect pinyin with a note of the correct one. Also 搜狗 has a huge range of words and phrases Include almost all the popular ones. Some people still uses 搜狗 words library even they don't use the IME.

Comment: @DanielYeung In Mandarine, although 辶 is called 走之 or 走之底, it's prototype actually isn't 走 (zou). As a native speaker, I have to admit that I didn't know that either until I looked it up. The prototype is 辵 (chuo).

Answer (score 1):

辶

I got it from [translate.google.com](https://translate.google.com/?hl=en#zh-CN/en/%E8%BE%B6)

I just hand or mouse write it, and I do not need to remember anything else.