# How to type strokes?

Tags: input-methods, strokes

In the same spirit as my [other question](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/12594/how-to-type-%E8%BE%B6-using-%E6%8B%BC%E9%9F%B3) about how to type certain radicals, I would like to know how to type strokes themselves.  I would like to be able to type all the strokes listed on the [Wikipedia](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Stroke_(CJKV_character)#/Use_in_computing) page.  Unlike radicals, however, to the best of my knowledge, not all of these strokes have a pronunciation associated to them (well, maybe if you allow more than one syllable, e.g. heng2zhe2zhe2gou1), and so I don't even know where to begin to try to input these.

Comment: Have you tried Google translation? You can hang write there.

Answer (score 3):

Wubihua input method. You can find this on older chinese phones hardware keys, or with a software keyboard on smartphones. It consists of just 5 buttons, each representing a basic stroke type. You tap them in the order of writing and suggestions of the most likely character come up. My personal favourite is multiling keyboard on Android. I have no idea how to input this on windows or mac. I only use the pinyin based microsoft chinese ime.

Answer (score 0):

Sougou input method.

```
If you know the name of the stroke:
```

Just input the name of that stroke, you could find it on the suggestion banner.

```
If you don't know the name:
```

1. You could try to input "u" firstly and see following the guide info
   on the banner.
2. Right click the input method choose "表情&符号"(smiley&symbols) -> "特殊符号"(specials) -> 中文字符.
3. Right click the input method choose "扩展功能"(Add-ins) -> "手写输入"(Handwriting), then draw the stroke on the board.

For me, I just search online and copy/paste if I need.